# UITextView becomes first responder but the pointer doesn't go there

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextview, becomefirstresponder

Ok so I have a rather weird issue: My UITextView becomes the first responder and I can tell because the keyboard appears, but what happens is that the pointer doesn't show up and the text can't be edited even if you type. This is the only UITextView in this controller, so it can't be triggering any other textview. Any ideas? Thanks :)

```
if (keyAuto) {
    [note becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

This is true, because if this BOOL is FALSE, it doesn't show at all. note is class level, so it can be called like this with no problems.

That's the code that creates note

```
note = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44 + lineHeight, widthv, heightNote)];
note.delegate = self;
note.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
[note setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];
[noteView addSubview:note];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, my bad, I forgot, I was trying to do that under viewDidLoad. Doing the same thing under viewDidAppear fixed all the issues. It was just that for some people viewDidLoad did the trick, so I expected the same, but apparently it didn't...